# c++/CLI прописать FlatStyle свойства всем checkbox'ам на форме

Tags: .net, c++-cli

Делаю на примере checkbox'ов по примеру кода из InitializeComponent()

```
for each (Control^ x in tab1->Controls) {
        if (x->GetType() == CheckBox::typeid) {
                    System::Drawing::Color x_border_color = System::Drawing::ColorTranslator::FromHtml(options::skin("OptionsForm", "check_box", "border_color"));
                    System::Drawing::Color x_checked_back_color = System::Drawing::ColorTranslator::FromHtml(options::skin("OptionsForm", "check_box", "checked_back_color"));
                    System::Drawing::Color x_mouse_down_back_color = System::Drawing::ColorTranslator::FromHtml(options::skin("OptionsForm", "check_box", "mouse_down_back_color"));
                    System::Drawing::Color x_mouse_over_back_color = System::Drawing::ColorTranslator::FromHtml(options::skin("OptionsForm", "check_box", "x_mouse_over_back_color"));
                    System::Drawing::Color x_back_color = System::Drawing::ColorTranslator::FromHtml(options::skin("OptionsForm", "back_color", "border_color"));
                    x->FlatStyle = System::Windows::Forms::FlatStyle::Flat;
                    x->BackColor = x_back_color;
                    x->FlatAppearance->BorderColor = x_border_color;
                    x->FlatAppearance->CheckedBackColor = x_checked_back_color;
                    x->FlatAppearance->MouseDownBackColor = x_mouse_down_back_color;
                    x->FlatAppearance->MouseOverBackColor = x_mouse_over_back_color;
                }
```

}

Пишет что FlatAppearance: не является членом "System::Windows::Forms::Control"
конечно, потому что FlatStyle из System::Windows::Forms::FlatStyle::Flat;
Но как тогда мне передать контролу X свойства FlatStyle?

А вот код из InitializeComponent() формы сгенерированный конструктором и тут не жалуется на данную проблему

```
this->fullsc->AutoSize = true;
        this->fullsc->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::FromArgb(static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(60)), static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(60)), 
            static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(60)));
        this->fullsc->FlatAppearance->BorderColor = System::Drawing::Color::White;
        this->fullsc->FlatAppearance->CheckedBackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Gray;
        this->fullsc->FlatAppearance->MouseDownBackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Black;
        this->fullsc->FlatAppearance->MouseOverBackColor = System::Drawing::Color::DarkRed;
        this->fullsc->FlatStyle = System::Windows::Forms::FlatStyle::Flat;
        this->fullsc->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Lucida Sans Unicode", 11.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
            static_cast<System::Byte>(204)));
        this->fullsc->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 96);
        this->fullsc->Name = L"fullsc";
        this->fullsc->Size = System::Drawing::Size(12, 11);
        this->fullsc->TabIndex = 5;
        this->fullsc->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
```

возможно правильным путем будет:
    for each (CheckBox^ x in tab1->Controls) {
однако после компиляции выходят ошибки вроде:
невозможно привести Label к CheckBox.
Получается x захватывает все контролы. Как бы сделать так чтобы он захватывал только чек боксы, ведь у нас нету OfType

Comment: спасибо! Это помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы отфильтровать элементы по определенному типу можно воспользоваться методом [`Enumerable.OfType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
for each (CheckBox^ x in Enumerable::OfType<CheckBox>(tab1->Controls))
```